# Should I include SDK or libraries projects in my application solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Should I include the projects of libraries and SDKs in my application solution?
Or should I only add references to the compiled assemblies?
What's a good practice?

These libraries and SDKs need to be updated and compiled from time to time.

Comment: Why the down vote? If you cared to downvote, maybe care to throw some minimal thoughts too?

Comment: Probably not, but maybe yes also.... it depends on your specific needs. In my **opinion** (because yes, this is an opinion based question), then the only time you should include them is if: 1. You have licence to modify and build them yourself. 2. The compiled DLLs are not already available 3. You need to make changes to the original code

Answer (score 1):

if you include project referances instead of dlls, each time you modify relevant 
projects, dlls will be updated as well

To reply more properly to  your question:

> Should I include the projects of libraries and SDKs in my application
>   solution

Yes, if they are external dll apart from your solutions projects

> ```
> Or should I only add references to the compiled assemblies?
> ```

This is not a good practice as you have opportunity as noted above.

Let me share a case in one of my customer.
I have several projects in solution. And I am allowed to put on customers pc only one project(main project runnable).

So on my pc I have project references and on customer pc, I have main project and compiled dlls.

Comment: The question is clearly seeking a yes/no answer... your **comment** does not provide that

Comment: Is what I said wrong then? I think this "answer" is clear to question

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's factually correct or not, it doesn't answer the question, it's just some related information. How does it answer the question? Are you saying "yes, you should because of X" or are you saying "no, but here is some information"?

Comment: @musefan No, the question is not looking only for a yes/no answer. I need some arguments as well. There's a reason I took time to ask here.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak I see what you're saying. This means the location of the assemblies need to be in some common location. Should I include the DLLs in my application repositories?

Comment: @DonBox if the dlls are external, you could create dll folder put them there and build. I dlls are updated, you should rebuild your project to reflect changes. Otherwise see answer

Comment: @DonBox: Yes you are. Just because you also want people to explain why they say yes or no doesn't mean it isn't a yes/no question... it's off topic here. SO is not for having discussions about opinions.

Comment: @musefan OK, what is SO for then?

Comment: @DonBox: Why don't you look through [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and see

Comment: @musefan You're one of those who prefer spending time arguing with a superior attitude without giving any actual help. You're not doing anything useful.

Comment: @DonBox I already gave you a useful comment. Now I am trying to help your understand how to use SO properly. It's not my fault you don't want to listen and take my advice. Instead you are interested in this supposed answer, which only suggest one benefit to including the projects and really is of no use at all on it's own.

Comment: You haven't contributed with anything useful. So far, you had 5 comments. 4 where just arguing, and 1 comment was "maybe yes, maybe not". Is this your understanding of what you should be doing on SO?

Comment: @DonBox: I updated that comment. Perhaps you should try reading things properly... that seems to be your problem in general though. And yeah... I should be informing people of the correct ways to use the site when they get it wrong. If you think your question is ok then why has it been closed? Why is the only answer you got useless as it stands? But hey, you carry on using this "answer" to make your decisions, see how well that works out for you

Comment: Reading things properly? Your original answer was "it depends, maybe yes, maybe no". You want me to read your mind maybe? I'm sorry do disappoint you, I can't do that. I see your answer now. Makes sense and it's helpful to me. What is wrong if you just answered with that from the start instead of trying to make me feel bad?

Comment: Also, every word we speak out is an opinion. If it happens it's true, then great. But it's still an opinion. I understand that SO should be question and answer oriented, and not about discussing ideas, but the things are not always white and black. Again, I truly understand the idea of making people ask specific question, such that there could be an answer. But it's not always that simple. The best answer is something which OP chooses to based on different things, including argumentation.

Comment: I'm not seeing SO just like a dumb place of Q&A, Q:"How do I declare a variable?" A: "Here's how you do it: var a = 1;"  Amusingly, I've seen questions with wrong answers.

Comment: @DonBox: If you understand what SO is, then you should know you shouldn't ask questions like this. If you want to ask a question like this then you should go find another site that is designed for it. And no, not everything we say is an opinion

Comment: @musefan SO is about helping and sharing knowledge. Some answers will always be based on individual experience. I've seen some really really great highly voted questions and answers related to optimization and performance which could easily go into the same category of "opinions".

Comment: @lebelinoz please see update, let me know if it is ok now